# Regex skipping periods inside of less than sign and greater than sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
$regLinks = "~meaning+?.{0,500}\\.~siU";
```

I need the last period, the `\\.` to be not inside of less than sign, and the greater than sign `<>`. So something like `<color blue.>` would be skipped over. How would I achieve that in regex?

```
$string "meaning: sad is when you are unhappy <blue green.> right now.";
```

^---So out of this, instead of stopping at `<blue green.>`, it should stop at

```
meaning: sad is when you are unhappy `<blue green.>` right now.
```

Comment: A look-ahead (appended to the `\.`) `(?![^>]*>)` can do that. Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @stribizhev I guess? :) I got one of them to work, and extract definitions from a dictionary website!

Comment: Yes, but you have `meaning` in the regex and `color` and `blue` in the example. That is not so clear. BTW, `g+?` matches 1 or more `g`.

Comment: Well, color blue was just an example.

Comment: @stribizhev I updated the code with more examples.

Comment: So, does this work for you: [`meaning.{0,500}\.(?![^>]*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/kK6rQ0/1)? Also, you might be interested in shortening the regex by replacing the limiting quantifier with just `*`: [`meaning\b.*\.(?![^>]*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/kK6rQ0/2).

Comment: @stribizhev Nope. But melopene's answer works!

Comment: Good you found a person whose way of thinking is similar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `.` in `.{0,500}` to `(?:[^<]|<[^>]*>)`.

`(?: )` is a regex group that doesn't capture (plain `( )` would also capture the string it matched).

`<` and `>` simply match themselves.

`[^>]*` matches 0 or more non-`>` characters.

In effect instead of matching "any character" (`.`), we match either

- a "normal" character (something that's not `<`)

or

- a `<...>` group (which consists of a `<`, followed by 0 or more non-`>` characters, followed by `>`)

Comment: Great answer! I appreciates it! :)

Comment: Oh. Btw, since I'm trying to learn regex as well, can you explain what the ?: mean? I know [^<] means not a <, and [^>] means not a >. But what does the < in the middle, next to the or, mean? And the *> at the end? What does that mean? Thanks.

Comment: It'll be more clear once I read it over a couple of times. Thanks for the update! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$regLinks = "~meaning+?(?:[^<]|<[^>]*>){0,500}\\.~siU";
```

I kept the `{0,500}` bit because I figured you had a reason for that, though it would be slightly more efficient to write:

```
$regLinks = "~meaning+?(?:[^<]+|<[^>]*>){0,500}\\.~siU";
```

However, that could consume arbitrary many characters.

Comment: That's less efficient if the match fails at the end, because now you have to go through combinatorial backtracking. If you want to optimize this case, you could use Friedl's "unrolling" trick: `[^<]*(?:<[^>]*>[^<]*)*`